# Convergence $\left(1+ \frac{\ln (1+1/n)^n}{\ln n^n}\right)^{\ln n^n} \to e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Convergence of **sequence** whose $n^{th}$ term is $$\left(1+ \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\ln n^n}\right)^{\ln n^n} \to e \\ T_n = e^{{\ln n^n}\ln\left(1+ \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\ln n^n}\right)}$$

After that what should i do? It is mentioned in [To test the convergence of a series whose nth term is $a_{n}=\left({\frac{\log n}{log(n+1)}}\right)^{n^2\log n}$ using Root test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584018/to-test-the-convergence-of-a-series-whose-nth-term-is-a-n-left-frac-log-n) But i did not understand part after "indeed" by 2nd Solution. Please help me in understanding it:

> $(\dots)$ indeed $$\left(1+\frac{\log(1+\frac1n)^n}{\log n^n}\right)^{\log n^n}=e^{\log n^n\cdot \log \left(1+\frac{\log(1+\frac1n)^n}{\log n^n}\right)}=e^{\log n^n\cdot \left(\frac{\log(1+\frac1n)^n}{\log n^n}+o\left(\frac{1}{logn^n}\right)\right)}=e^{\left(\log(1+\frac1n)^n+o(1)\right)}\to e$$

Or is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{\ln n^n} \to 0$$

indeed

- $\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to \ln e=1$
- $\ln n^n\to \infty$

therefore

$$\left(1+ \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\ln n^n}\right)^{\ln n^n}=\left[\left(1+ \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\ln n^n}\right)^{\frac{\ln n^n}{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}}\right]^{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}  \to e^1=e$$

indeed let $m=\frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{\ln n^n} \to 0$ and thus

$$\left(1+ \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\ln n^n}\right)^{\frac{\ln n^n}{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}}=(1+m)^\frac1m \to e$$

Comment: Sir in ur post u have expanded in terms of Order of ($\frac{1}{\ln n^n}$). can u pls elaborate on that?

Comment: @gimsui pls see the uploaded image above ... Is it expansion of $ln(1+f(x)) = f(x)-(f(x))^2 /2 + ... $ But here why numerator term is ignored and only $\frac{1}{\ln n^n}$ is considered

Comment: @gimsui Sir pls have a look. I started real analysis and so i am finding it bit difficult at some places.

Comment: Asap I’ll give some more details.